# Configure Eclipse CDT to use g++

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows-7, cygwin, eclipse-cdt

I have cygwin installed, and I want to use Eclipse with CDT for development under **Windows 7**. However, I get following error:

```
**** Build of configuration Default for project hello_cpp ****

make all 
g++ -O2 -g -Wall -fmessage-length=0   -c -o hello_cpp.o hello_cpp.cpp
process_begin: CreateProcess(C:\cygwin\bin\g++.exe, g++ -O2 -g -Wall -fmessage-length=0 -c -o hello_cpp.o hello_cpp.cpp, ...) failed.
make (e=5): Access denied.

make: *** [hello_cpp.o] Error 5

**** Build Finished ****
```

- I'm able to use g++ as standalone compiler.
- cygwin /bin folder is
  added to path.

After googling I found out that `C:\cygwin\bin\g++.exe` is a cygwin symbolic link and Windows doesn't understand it and I need to point to the g++-3 location directly. How do I do it?

Comment: do a "ls -l C:\cygwin\bin\g++.exe" and from the output ( A -> B ) copy B as actual location.

Comment: I don't really understand how to configure eclipse(or make) to execute the right command.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you've done something wrong and need to start over again. Just installed Cygwin and Eclipse CDT (Indigo) on my Windows 7 and all works fine and auto-magicaly for me.

Here's what I did and I think you need to do:

1. Get the latest [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/setup.exe) (yes, get it again! get rid of the old one just to be sure)
2. During the installation make sure to select `gcc`, `gcc-g++` and `make` (I additionally installed couple of other things like `gcc4`, `w32api` but it's optional)
3. Start Cygwin terminal to init all configuration files, etc. See if g++ executes and close the terminal.
4. Add `C:\cygwin\bin` (or wherever else you installed it) to your Environment `PATH` variable
5. Get Eclipse CDT, extract it somewhere and start it up.
6. Go to `File -> New Project -> C++ Project` and select `Hello World C++ Project`. You should see the `Cygwin GCC` in the `Toolchains` list.
   [image]
7. Create the Project, build and run it!

Done!

Build output:

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project TestApp ****

make all 
Building file: ../src/TestApp.cpp
Invoking: Cygwin C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/TestApp.d" -MT"src/TestApp.d" -o "src/TestApp.o" "../src/TestApp.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/TestApp.cpp

Building target: TestApp.exe
Invoking: Cygwin C++ Linker
g++  -o "TestApp.exe"  ./src/TestApp.o   
Finished building target: TestApp.exe

**** Build Finished ****
```

Comment: Just as a note, if you've already opened Eclipse, you'll need to close it and reopen before any changes to Environment PATH will take effect!

Answer (score 1):

You can go to

> Project Properties Page > C / C++ Build > Settings > Tool Settings

And change the command as you want. Documentation [here](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_prop_build_toolchain.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Refer this [link](http://permadi.com/blog/2011/09/setting-up-android-jni-projects-in-windows-eclipse-and-sequoyah/), it shows how to setup eclipse for native development with ease. everything is done in eclipse except setting environment variables.